# Fetch contact who has birthday today

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to fetch information of contact who has birthday today(i.e current day). Below is my program.
 It was working properly when last month i tested but now it does not return the correct data.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE };

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    String date = "'%-" + (month > 8 ? month : "0" + (month + 1)) + "-"
            + (day > 9 ? day : "0" + day) + "'";

    String where = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND "
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + " IN ( "
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY
            + " )  AND "
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE + " LIKE "
            + date;

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME;
    Cursor c=mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, where,
            selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

My cursor c is null. can someone point out the mistake I have made in my logic.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to debug and check value of each `argument` you are passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is where you handle the month value. Since October equals 9 you end up with the string "%-9-08".

You can add even more logic to handle this case but this is really not the right way to do these things.
Try this:

```
String date = "'%-" + DateFormat.format("MM-dd",cal).toString() + "'";
```